# Validation rule to prevent two fields being filled in

Tags: validation

I am trying to create a validation rule which checks whether Field A OR Field B or no field is filled in. Basically, we want to disallow that both fields are filled in at the same time. 
I have created the below validation rule, but it gives me an error when I try to leave both fields blank.
Is there an easier way of expressing this?

```
OR( 
AND(checkbox__c , NOT(ISBLANK(Lookup__c))), 
AND(NOT(checkbox__c), ISBLANK(Lookup__c)), 
AND(NOT(checkbox__c), NOT(ISBLANK(Lookup__c))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can understand from your below statement is that you want to throw an error when both the fields are filled.

> we want to disallow that both fields are filled in at the same time

If that's the case, then your validation rule should be something like this

```
AND(checkbox__c, NOT(ISBLANK(Lookup__c)))
```

Assuming `checkbox__c` is a checkbox field, hence above rule will fire only when checkbox is checked and lookup field has a value in it.